# Import csv file data to plsql table using python

Tags: python, linux

I have a csv file which contains 60000 rows. I need to insert this data into postgres database table. Is there any way to do this to reduce time to insert data from file to database without looping? Please help me
Python Version : 2.6

```
Database : postgres
 table: keys_data

 File Structure
1,ED2,'FDFDFDFDF','NULL'
2,ED2,'SDFSDFDF','NULL
```

Comment: Why do you assume that looping will add time? Whatever the tool, you will have to read all the lines and insert all the rows. I would use the `csv` module to parse the input file, `executemany` to insert rows in batches and eventually `commit` every n rows to limit the size of the rollback file. Other possible optimizations: remove indexes before inserting and (re-)create them after.

Comment: You are expected to perform basic research and make an effort. Also see [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158289) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Postgres can read CSV directly into a table with the [`COPY` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-copy.html). This either requires you to be able to place files directly on the Postgres server, or data can be piped over a connection with `COPY FROM STDIN`.

The `\copy` command in Postgres' `psql` command-line client will read a file locally and insert using `COPY FROM STDIN` so that's probably the easiest (and still fastest) way to do this.

Note: this doesn't require any use of Python, it's native functionality in Postgres and not all or most other RDBs have the same functionality.

Comment: could you please provide sample approach, I am very new to these concepts.

Comment: I found this code COPY country FROM '/usr1/proj/bray/sql/country_data';
bit how could i execute this from python script

Comment: @sireeshaj Why do you need to do it from a Python script? Like I mentioned, probably all you need to is use Postgres front-end [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-psql.html). For example `\copy keys_data from yourdata.csv`

Comment: In my requirement I should do it from script only

Answer (score 0):

I've performed similar task, the only exception is that my solution is python 3.x based. I am sure you can find equivalent code of this solution. Code is pretty self explanatory.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def insert_in_postgre(table_name, df):

    #create engine object
    engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@hostname/database_name')

    #push dataframe in given database engine
    df.head(0).to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='replace',index=False ) 
    conn = engine.raw_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    output = io.StringIO()
    df.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
    output.seek(0)
    contents = output.getvalue()
    cur.copy_from(output, table_name, null="") 
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
```